# Problem in my form submit flow, form data is too big

Tags: php, cookies, state

Here is my flow:

> Form A post data to input.php as B
>
> If data is invalid, B send data and
>   error code into cookie and redirect to
>   referer url (now is Form A)
>
> Form A read data, error code in cookie, restate
>   the form and display error message. The last thing is delete the cookie.

My problem is: How I still keep this flow if form data too heavy, because cookie size is limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. A cookie is limited to 4Kb. The only option you have is to store the data in a cache, or database (with an ID), and send that ID to back in the cookie.

When you redirect to your Form A, you can then re-read the data from the cache or database with the ID from the cookie.

Comment: surely somewhere in best practice rules it would say not to store invalid data in a database.....

Comment: I think what he mean is we should store view state data into a session table

Answer (score 1):

you could also have the form submit to the same page. Then you eliminate the problem of redirecting between pages and struggling to persist the data.

Comment: Agreed, and then just check for isset($_POST) to populate your fields

Comment: My design is separate input and output. Co I can't do this, because it will break my design :p